# SQL Server 2008 R2 : Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting the following error

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string

I can't get it to run properly please help me, here is my code (don't shame my loop i just need it to work).

The thing is i have a closed list with contracts IDs and a table with different dates and dates called `#PERIODO` it contains `datetime` type.

```
WHILE (SELECT TOP 1 FECHA1 FROM #PERIODO) > 0 
BEGIN
    SET @MES_ANTERIOR   = (SELECT TOP 1 FECHA1 FROM #PERIODO ORDER BY FECHA1 ASC)
    SET @MES_EN_CURSO   = (SELECT TOP 1 B.FECHA1 FROM (SELECT TOP 2 A.FECHA1 FROM #PERIODO A ORDER BY FECHA1 ASC ) B ORDER BY B.FECHA1 DESC)
    SET @MES_3          = (SELECT TOP 1 FECHA3 FROM #PERIODO ORDER BY FECHA1 ASC)
    SET @MES_4          = (SELECT TOP 1 B.FECHA3 FROM (SELECT TOP 2 A.FECHA3 FROM #PERIODO A ORDER BY FECHA3 ASC ) B ORDER BY B.FECHA3 DESC)
    SET @MES_ANT        = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@MES_ANTERIOR,112),8) -- SELECT @MES_ANT
    SET @MES_CURR       = LEFT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),@MES_EN_CURSO,112),8) -- SELECT @MES_CURR  

     EXEC('IF OBJECT_ID(''WORK.DBO.OPERACIONES_ABIF_'+@MES_CURR+''', ''U'') IS NOT NULL 
            DROP TABLE WORK.DBO.OPERACIONES_ABIF_'+@MES_CURR+'    ')  

     SET @SQL1 = 'SELECT DISTINCT 
         A.* 
         INTO  WORK.DBO.OPERACIONES_ABIF_'+@MES_CURR+'
         FROM  BDGESTION.DBO.BASE_RIESGOS_PROD_ALTAIR_'+@MES_CURR+' A   WHERE '

     SET @SQL2 = ' A.NUM_OPERACION IN ( 
                 SELECT 
                    B.NUM_CONTRATO 
                    FROM (
                        SELECT NUM_CONTRATO 
                        FROM 
                            ( SELECT * FROM #OPER WHERE FECHA_INICIO IS NOT NULL) H 
                        WHERE       H.FECHA_INICIO <  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),'+@MES_EN_CURSO+',23) AS VARCHAR ) 

                                AND H.FECHA_INICIO >= CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12),'+@MES_ANTERIOR+',23) AS VARCHAR ) 
                                ) B 
                        WHERE 
                            B.NUM_CONTRATO IS NOT NULL ) '

        EXEC (@SQL1 + @SQL2)    

        DELETE FROM #PERIODO 
        WHERE FECHA1 = @MES_ANTERIOR 
    END
```

Comment: The error appears in @SQL2 = ' '

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem would appear to be these lines:

```
WHERE  H.FECHA_INICIO <  CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), ' + @MES_EN_CURSO + ', 23) AS VARCHAR)
```

Presumably, you want the `cast()` outside the aggregation:

```
WHERE  H.FECHA_INICIO < ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @MES_EN_CURSO + ', 23) + '
```

However, I don't recommend this as a solution.  The correct solution is to pass the value in as a *parameter*.  Your query is too complex (and messy) for me to attempt that.  You should look at the documentation for `sp_executesql` on how to properly construct dynamic SQL with parameters.

Comment: Yes is a little bit messy cause i was trying to fix the error and i need it to go through 12 years of monthly tables.. That and the fact that i jsut learn SQL so i dont know if theres a better way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should `print @SQL2` as you go through the loop so you can see the incorrect value.

It would be helpful to show how you `declare @MES_EN_CURSO` and `declare @MES_ANTERIOR`.